# Making button flash in Netbeans-Java

Tags: netbeans-8

I want to know how to make a button flash or reapond in some way when the mouse cursor is hovered over it.I am new to programming so if u can please make it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Netbeans you can click in the button with right click and go to properties there you will find many options look for the one that says 'icon' and click on the '...' button next to it, there you can add in image to the button, after that you will scroll down and look for the option tha says 'rolloverIcon' and you will do the same and add the othe image you want for you button, that will be the image for when you put your cursor over the button, there is also an option for 'pressedIcon', all of this assuming you already have each image or icon for each situation, my recommendation you could try using GIMP or PhotShop to use the same icon but changing the size, so when is Over is bigger os smaller to the normal state or the press one.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks!! it did the job.